# Filtering of IsotopeData results for EnergyDecay option

Tags: list-manipulation

When I use

```
IsotopeData["Tellurium110", "DecayEnergies"]
IsotopeData["Tellurium110", "DecayModes"]
```

I'll have

```
{Quantity[4245.0, "Kiloelectronvolts"], Quantity[2723.2, Kiloelectronvolts"]}
{"BetaPlusDecay", "AlphaEmission"}
```

This command gives me all energy decays of all possible decays of this isotope. How can I filter the results for a specific decay mode? For example, I want to have only information about the beta decay of this isotope. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html):

```
Pick[
 IsotopeData["Tellurium110","DecayEnergies"],
 IsotopeData["Tellurium110","DecayModes"],
 "BetaPlusDecay"
]

(* Quantity[4245.`5.", "Kiloelectronvolts"] *)
```

Or, slightly shorter:

```
Pick[##,"BetaPlusDecay"]&@@
 (IsotopeData["Tellurium110",#]&)/@
  {"DecayEnergies","DecayModes"}
```